# ASP.NET MVC: Partial view to show part of a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have two views that render a table on each. Most of the tables are shared between both views so I want to be able to reuse the view code for them both.

**Table 1**

```
Column A   |   Column B
1          |   2
4          |   8
```

**Table 2**

```
Column A   |   Column B   |   Column C
1          |   2          |   7
4          |   8          |   2
```

Obviously, my actual tables are a lot more complicated than the example above, which only serves to compound the problem. Because of how tables are written in HTML, there seems to me no good way to cut out the stuff I want to reuse while still having the ability to add to it.

Using tables, are there any methods I can employ to reuse the code or will I have to move away from using tables?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Why would tables prevent you from developing re-usable code?

Comment: Because how you must write a table in HTML, you define your columns by writing a td inside each row. I can't just 'cut out' a couple of columns, and reuse them inside a different table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just create a view that specializes in building a table given a specific model that includes all the column and row information? That way, you can use the view anywhere you want, and the model you give it will determine how many columns and rows there are.

#### Edit

I don't think you're quite understanding my point, so I'll use some code. Right now you probably have a model that looks something like this:

```
public class Something
{
    public string ValueA {get;set;}
    public string ValueB {get;set;}
    public string ValueC {get;set;}
}
```

And your view probably looks something like this:

```
<table><tr><th>Column A</th><th>Column B</th><th>Column C</th></tr>
    <%foreach(var something in Model.Somethings) {%>
       <tr>
           <td><%:something.ValueA%></td>
           <td><%:something.ValueB%></td>
           <td><%:something.ValueA%></td>
       </tr>
    <%}%>
</table>
```

Well, as you have noticed, this doesn't lend itself well to simply columns from the table. One solution would be to set some options on the module to determine which columns get included, and then throw a bunch of `if/then` statements into your view. But I think a better solution would be to make a new Model class that looks more like this:

```
public class TableModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Headers {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> Rows {get;set;}
}
```

Then your model looks more like this:

```
<table><tr>
    <%foreach(var header in Model.Headers) {%>
        <th><%:header%></th>
    <%}%></tr>
    <%foreach(var row in Model.Rows) {%>
       <tr>
       <%foreach(var cell in row) {%>
           <td><%:cell%></td>
        <%}%>
       </tr>
    <%}%>
</table>
```

As you can see, there is nothing in this view code that ties itself explicitly to your original data type, so it can be reused for any table you want to create throughout your entire application. Your controller becomes responsible for creating a TableModel object from the data that you want to represent. If a particular column gets included in that model, it will be displayed. If not, it won't.

Obviously, like your example, this is extremely simplified, but it should give you the general idea. The `DataTable` class, which is already part of .NET, might already have everything you need, so you won't even have to create your own `TableModel` class. It's already got some nice functionality around adding and removing columns, rows, etc.

Comment: I do already, each view has it's own view model that it could use to create the table, however quite a bit of the view model is shared and it just so happens that that shared information is displayed using a table. There is about 400 lines of view code that I'll need to duplicate in order to recreate just the partial bit of the table...

Comment: @ajbeaven 400 lines in view :( what are you upto? i guess you need to consult someone on this

Comment: @ajbeaven: I don't think you understood my point. See my edit.

Comment: Question though: you don't think it's a bad idea to tie the view model down to how the data will be displayed - similarly how it's not recommended to pass a SelectList to you view? If instead we no longer wanted to use a table to display this data, we'd want to change the viewmodels, and then need to change how our application models are mapped to them.

Comment: @ajbeaven: If you talk to the purists, tables should only be used to display "tabular data," anyway. If the data you're displaying is tabular, then it makes sense to put it in a view model that represents a data table. If it's really just supposed to represent the object that you're displaying, then it probably doesn't make much sense. Without knowing more about what kind of code you're using that takes 400 lines in your view, I can't really guess at the very best strategy for your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a HTMLHelper for the common code. I would pass the condition to the helper to determine what to output.

Answer (score 0):

Try thinking of the problem in two steps.  One is generating the headers and grabbing the columns that you need, another is actually rendering the Html.  Then you can call a method like

```
RenderTable( string[] columnsINeed )
```

Which will render the table columns you need.

The way you need to render HTML shouldn't prevent you from writing re-usable code.